# how to configure properties for mvc spring bean controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, properties, controller

Is there a special way for doing this?
What i got is:

1. config.properties with param.key=value
2. web.xml with ContextLoaderListener that reads the configuration
3. pages-servlet.xml that defines servlet beans.

What I want is to configure one of the beans in pages-servlet.xml with param.key.
I'm using `<property name="myField" value="${param.key}"/>` in the xml but I see that the field is configured with `${param.key}` instead of 'value'.

What is the right way to configure the bean?

Ok, I solved it by importing application context file that defines configuration bean into pages-servlet.xml.
It works, but seems very wrong.

Comment: The Spring Framework has fairly detailed documentation, have you read the user guide? http://springframework.org/documentation

Comment: Yes, but couldn't find the answer. If you can point me to the right section instead of giving the general link, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property placeholder is what you want.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties" />
    <bean id="mybean" class="...">
        <property name="xxx" value="${prop.value}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: yup (+1) and here's the link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Comment: This is exactly what I'm using. The problem that it is defined in one of the libraries of the web project and for some reason cannot be seen in the servlet context just like all other beans, despite  ContextLoaderListener. It worked after I've imported configuration bean into servlet context file.